# How do you calculate the probability for a Head-Tail series of 5 out of 10 coin flips? (HTHTHTHTHTHT)

Tags: probability

I am looking to calculate the probability of a HEAD-TAIL 5x repeat out of 10 coin flips. In other words I am looking for the propability of getting HEAD-TAIL 5 times in a row if coin is being flipped 10 times. (HTHTHTHTHT).
Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you know how many possible results are there after flipping a coin $10$ times?

Comment: It is the same as the probability of HHHHHHHHHH or HTTTTTTTTH or any combination of 10 H and T. Why is that?

Comment: Yes, but as far as I can see this does not answer the questions about the probability for the sequence HT being repated 5 times (HT-HT-HT-HT-HT), or is it?

Comment: The probability that the sequence $HT$ is repeated five times is the probability that the sequence $HTHTHTHTHT$ occurs.  I think the grouping in the question phrasing is distracting you.

Comment: But if you want to think about in terms of grouping....

The probability that the first two flips yields $HT$ is $1/4$.  Then what's the probability that happens 5 times in a row?

Answer (score 2):

There are $2^n$ possible coin flip sequences of length $n$ and you are asking for the probability that **one** particular sequence is flipped.  Because the events in the sequence are independent and uniformly distributed, the event space of sequences of $n$ flips is also uniformly distributed.

Let me ask you a "simpler" question (it's actually the same by the above point).

There are three rabbits in a hat:  one is blue, one is red, and one is green.  You reach into a hat and pull out a rabbit at random.  What's the probability you pulled the green rabbit??

Once you have that, let's rephrase your problem:  There are $2^{10}$ pieces of paper in a hat.  Written on each piece of paper is a unique sequence of $10$ $H$s and $T$s.  You reach into a hat and pull out a slip of paper at random.  What's the probability you pulled out the slip with $TTTHHTHTTH$?  How about the probability you pulled the slip with $HTTHTHTHTH$?  What about $HTHTTTTTTT$?

Comment: Yes, that's right

Comment: Wouldn't thaty be1 out of 3?

Comment: I am asking about the probability of the same sequence of 2 (HT) being flipped 5 times.

Comment: Thank you for your clarifications. Appreciated.